# Symfony 3 TokenAuthenticator with GuardAuthenticator: destroy old session and token If user is already logged in

Tags: php, session, symfony

i want to perform a basic Api Key authentication system through request parameter, eg: http://example.com/foo.php?MyKey=far

If Api Key authentication is performed, but the user is already logged in (eg. with the "remember me" function) i want destroy the old session and the old user token if the old user and new authenticated user through Api Key is not equal.

My code work good! i want know if this is the best way (best == security)

TokenAuthenticator.php

```
<?php
namespace ACME\MyBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\Token\PostAuthenticationGuardToken;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorage;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\UsernameNotFoundException;
use ACME\MyBundle\Security\User\MyProvider;
use ACME\MyBundle\Security\User\User;

class TokenAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    /**
     * @var MyProvider
     */
    private $provider;

    /**
     * @var TokenStorage
     */
    private $tokenStorage;


    /**
     * @param MyProvider   $provider
     * @param TokenStorage $tokenStorage
     */
    function __construct(MyProvider $provider, TokenStorage $tokenStorage){
        $this->provider     = $provider;
        $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
    }


    /**
    * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorInterface::getCredentials()
    */
    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        $MyKey = $request->get('MyKey', null);

        if ( empty($MyKey) ) {
            return null;
        }

        return array(
            'request' => $request,
            'MyKey'   => $MyKey,
        );
    }


    /**
     * @see \Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\GuardAuthenticatorInterface::getUser()
     */
    public function getUser($credentials, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $username = $this->provider->getUsernameForMyKey($credentials['MyKey']);

        if( !empty($username) ){

            if( $newUser = $this->provider->loadUserByUsername($username) ){

                /* @var $oldToken PostAuthenticationGuardToken */
                if (null !== $oldToken = $this->tokenStorage->getToken() ) {

                    /* @var $oldUser User */
                    if ( is_object($oldUser = $oldToken->getUser()) ) {


                        if( !$oldUser->isEqualTo($newUser) ){
                            if( isset($credentials['request']) ){

                                /* @var $request Request */
                                $request = $credentials['request'];

                                if ( is_object($request) ) {

                                    $session = $request->getSession();
                                    $session->invalidate();
                                }
                            }

                            $this->tokenStorage->setToken(null);
                        } 
                    }
                }

                return $newUser;
            }
        }

        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(); 
    }
```

services.yml

```
# src/ACME/MyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml
services:
    token_authenticator:
        class: ACME\MyBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator
        arguments: ["@my_provider", "@security.token_storage"]
```

security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        guard:
            authenticators: [token_authenticator]
```

Comment: tokenStorage will at this point always be null - your solution is not working at all